# Use MS Graph API to schedule an event and set organizer

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-graph-calendar

We are using graph api's to set up group health care sessions and need a way to set the organizer and/or give another member of the team similar functionality to the organizer.

Specifically, we want to be able to allow another member of the team manage breakout room functionality.

Use Case

- Bob TheOrganizer wants to allow Sally AssistantOrganizer(moderator) to manage breakout rooms

All suggestions welcome!
thx

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there's no way to 'delegate' owner role, you can only schedule meetings using Sally's account

Comment: I don't think you can set the organizer, the one  who creates event with his account will become the organizer AFAIK.

Comment: You can't delegate the organizer nor it contains any moderator concept. Say, if you're creating/organizing the event then you will be the organizer. Being said that [you can try this approach using Outlook](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/4401-outlook-change-meeting-organizer-owner.html) - this way you can move the ownership to other person and  able to maintain the changes moving forward (no two persons can manage the ownership)!!

Comment: Does it helped?

Comment: Thanks but not solving the issue. we have a work around for now but hope there will be enhanced graph API support.